# Deleting an operating system entry from bootloader menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, bootloader

yesterday I installed Windows 8.1 while I had Windows 7 already installed. Now, once I boot up my laptop, it asks me whether I want Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 booted up. I want that to go away, I want to uninstall Windows 7, and I read somewhere that all I had to do is format the Windows 7 partition, but it still asks me which OS I want to use. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search 'msconfig' and open it up. Select the 'Boot' tab, and click on Windows 7 and hit the Delete button. After that, hit 'Apply' and hit 'Ok' and restart. :]

Comment: Done it now, once I test, I'll mark this right.